# NGXS: Separate actions into separate files

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, action, ngxs

I am using NGXS in my Angular 8 app. Currently, all action handlers (functions with `@Action` decorator) are implemented in `state.ts`, making the file way too long to read. I managed to separate the selectors in a different file, using the `@Selector([StateName])` syntax. But I can't make this work with `@Actions`. Ideally, I would be able to move my 20 or so actions to 5 different files.

How can this be done with NGXS?

Comment: No, this is not possible. Actions are closely related to the `@State` decorator. They both add static metadata to a class and then NGXS reads this metadata from a class.

Answer (score 2):

The best approach I found to mitigate the issue is to break down the state into smaller chunks, making it more manageable and easier to read, can the state structure be broken down into smaller parts or is it all interlinked together? Maybe look into using sub-states? https://www.ngxs.io/advanced/sub-states

Answer (score 0):

Can you move logic to functions and call these functions from methods?

```
// app.state
@State<AppStateModel>({
    name: 'app',
    defaults: defaultAppState,
})
export class AppState {

    @Action(AppInitialized)
    testAction(context: StateContext<AppStateModel>, action: AppInitialized) {
        return testActionFromOtherFile(context, action);
    }
}

// test.action.ts
export function testActionFromOtherFile(context: StateContext<AppStateModel>, action: AppInitialized) {
    // do stuff
}
```